# Why do the sabeans have so much in common with Islam?

Tags: history, ahlul-kitab

People are saying that Islam is a copy of sabeans and that prophet Muhammad (saw) copied from them. The sabeans is used to perform hajj, pray 5 times, wash themselves after intercourse just like Muslims. I got confused and I researched a little. I heard they go back to David(as).so do they follow the zabur? Can someone please educate me more about them.